# How to get objects from object of objects by unknown parent key but with specific key & value in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this data:

```
data: {
    first: {
        call: false
    },
    second: {
        call: true
    },
    third: {
        call: true
    },
    fourth: {
        call: false
    },
}
```

and I want to get from data only the objects that their `call` field is true.

This is the expected results:

```
data: {
    second: {
        call: true
    },
    third: {
        call: true
    },
}
```

Do you have an idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields": {
  "data": {
    "$objectToArray": "$data"
    }
  }
},
{
 "$addFields": {
  "data": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$data",
      "as": "d",
      "cond": {
        $eq: [
          "$$d.v.call",
          true
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
{
 $addFields: {
   data: {
       "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Explained:

1. Use objectToArray to convert to array
2. Use $filter to match only the true calls
3. Use arrayToObject to convert back to object

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hMLez3YP52B)

You can do as well in single operation as follow:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$addFields": {
  "data": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": {
          "$objectToArray": "$data"
        },
        "as": "d",
        "cond": {
          $eq: [
            "$$d.v.call",
            true
          ]
         }
        }
       }
     }
   }
  }
])
```

[Playground 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pr7fo-9xNJ0)

But in general it is best practice to avoid unknown keys and enumerate similar sub-objects in arrays instead of objects  , for your case maybe is worth to consider changing the schema as follow:

[Schema change option to consider maybe???](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bLC2l7RRCl7)